# How do I record changes to a cell in Numbers via AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, numbers

I'm very new to AppleScript so bear with me. What I am trying to achieve is for every time I run the script, the current value of a cell is copied into a cell, one column to the right of when I last ran the script, so the first time it puts the value of A1 into B1, then A1 into C1, then A1 into D1 ect. How would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Please [edit] your question to include the script you have so far so we can try to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is written as more of a *proof of concept* to show some *logic* in accomplishing the task. There may be a better way to *code* it, but I do not really do much **AppleScript** with **Numbers**, maybe someone else (CJK) can present some different *code*.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* was tested under **macOS High Sierra** and **Numbers**, *version 5.1 (5683)*, with a default *document* using the *basic blank template* and as *coded* works per what was mentioned in the OP. The *example* **AppleScript** *code* assumes that **Numbers** is already running with the default *document* opened.

As coded, with `set n to 1`, if the *value* of, e.g., **A1** is not *missing value*, then the *value* of the next *cell* in that  *row* whose *value* **is** *missing value*, then gets the *value* of the first *cell* of that *row*. In this case the *value* of, e.g., **A1**.

Setting `set n to 2`, and so on, acts on that *row* and the *value* of that *rows* first *cell*, if not *missing value*, then get set to the *value* of the next *cell* of that *row* whose *value* **is** *missing value*.

<sub>**Note:** The setting or changing the *value* of a *cell* is not *set* until *focus* is removed from that *cell*. This normally occurs when pressing a *key*, e.g., *tab*, *enter*, *arrow* or when clicking elsewhere in the *document* with the mouse. I'm mentioning this so when you go to test the *code* and you typed something in e.g. **A1**, its *value* is still *missing value* until *focus* is moved elsewhere.</sub>

```applescript
tell application "Numbers"
    set n to 1
    tell row n of table 1 of sheet 1 of document 1
        if the value of its first cell is not missing value then
            set v to value of its first cell
            set c to its cell count
            set i to 2
            set flag to true
            repeat while flag is true and i is less than c + 1
                if the value of cell n of column i is missing value then
                    set its value of cell n of column i to v
                    set flag to false
                else
                    set i to i + 1
                end if
            end repeat
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>